Python testcontainers initialise Postgres with SQL file?
How to init Postgres with SQL file ?
Have found https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/4841, but with_init_script not available in python  version.

From https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python/pull/572/files, solution is to:
postgres_container = PostgresContainer("postgres:16-alpine")
    script = Path(__file__).parent / "dump.sql"
    postgres_container.with_volume_mapping(host=str(script), container=f"/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/{script.name}")

This must be done before postgres_container.start()
dump.sql was generated with /Library/PostgreSQL/16/bin/pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres postgres  --file=dump.sql
Interesting, following code did not worked with same file:
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    with open("dump.sql", 'r') as f:
        cursor.execute(f.read())

    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("Restore successful!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Restore failed:", e)

Had error when inserting data.
With --schema-only was working fine.
If anybody knows why, please share.
